# Getting more matches than the expected in python

Tags: python, regex

I was trying to do some pattern matching in python. But I am not able to understand why I get a second match when i just match for only one.

```
import re

def Main():
    m = "12312312ranger12312319"
    pattern = re.compile('(\d$)')
    r = pattern.search(m)
    if r:
        print "Matched " + r.group(0) +  " Second " + r.group(1)
    else:
        print "Not Matched"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

This gives me an output like this

```
Matched 9 Second 9
```

I am thinking r.group(1) should not be there at all. Am i understanding it wrongly ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

group(0) will always returns the whole text that was matched regardless of if it was captured in a group or not. See example:

```
import re

def Main():
    m = "12312312ranger12312319"
    pattern = re.compile('\d(\d$)')
    r = pattern.search(m)
    if r:
        print r.group(0) + ' ' + r.group(1)
    else:
        print "Not Matched"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main()
```

Output:

```
19 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're both matching and capturing the last digit which was at the end of a line. So group(0) and group(1) refer to the same. `(\d$)` not only do capturing but also it will do the job of matching. So finally `group(0)` prints the matched characters and `group(1)` prints all the characters which are present inside the captured group index 1.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of `$` sign , you match the end of string ! and also as `9` is the first and The entire matched pattern the `group(0)` (The entire match) and `group(1)` (The first parenthesized subgroup) both return `9` .

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HNi5Zw49emuWuo3P)

Now if you dont want `group(1)` you need to remove grouping from your pattern and use `r'\d$'` , but note that `$` matched the last character `9` .

from wiki :

> group() Returns one or more subgroups of the match. If there is a single argument, the result is a single string; if there are multiple arguments, the result is a tuple with one item per argument. Without arguments, group1 defaults to zero (the whole match is returned). If a groupN argument is zero, the corresponding return value is the entire matching string; if it is in the inclusive range [1..99], it is the string matching the corresponding parenthesized group. If a group number is negative or larger than the number of groups defined in the pattern, an IndexError exception is raised. If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that did not match, the corresponding result is None. If a group is contained in a part of the pattern that matched multiple times, the last match is returned.

example :

```
>>> m = re.match(r"(\w+) (\w+)", "Isaac Newton, physicist")
>>> m.group(0)       # The entire match
'Isaac Newton'
>>> m.group(1)       # The first parenthesized subgroup.
'Isaac'
>>> m.group(2)       # The second parenthesized subgroup.
'Newton'
>>> m.group(1, 2)    # Multiple arguments give us a tuple.
('Isaac', 'Newton')
```

Comment: But why r.group(1) also returns a 9 ?

Comment: i think its because of that `9` is the first and The entire match !

Comment: Here there are two matches (\w+) (\w+) with a space between them. I can understand that it will be in group 1 and 2. In my case all I am matching is a single digit match. Coming from a perl background where you say $1 for the first match. There should never be a second match.

Comment: @Arman yep , but attend to my edit ! in python when you put the pattern in parenthesize (actually grouping the regex) the `group(1)` return the first group matching , if you try `\d$` instead yours , you'll see that there `group(1)` return `IndexError: no such group
`